# Why does this timer that uses a global flag variable not work when optimizations are enabled?

Tags: c, optimization, signals

With the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

long long int cpt=0,nb=3;
bool out=false;
void alarm_handler() {out=true;}

void prime()
{
  while (nb++) {
    for (long long int j=2;j<nb;j++) {
      if ((nb % j)==0) {cpt++;break;}
    }
    if (out) return;
  }
}
      
int main()
{
  struct itimerval timer;
  bzero(&timer,sizeof(timer));
  timer.it_value.tv_sec=1;
  signal(SIGALRM,alarm_handler);
  int res=setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&timer,NULL);
  if (res<0) perror("error setting signal original timer");
  else prime();
  printf("cpt=%Ld nb=%Ld\n",cpt,nb);
  fflush(stdout);
  exit(0);
}
```

The program behaves correctly when compiled with gcc or clang without optimizations. However, as soon as -O is used, it never ends, as if the value of the `out` variable was never read inside the `prime()` function (I am sure the variable is properly set, as it is possible to add a print in the handler, and it is set).
Is it possible to force the compiler to keep on checking the value of `out` in `prime()` ?

Comment: Try: `volatile bool out=false;`

Comment: `out` [must](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p5) be declared `volatile sig_atomic_t`. Using any other type to communicate with a signal handler is undefined behaviour.